# 301 site redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Just finished building a new site for a client and the old sites URL structure was basically /index.php?pageid=1, /index.php?pageid=2 etc

How do I put a redirect on all of the legacy pages

The current site uses domain.com/blog-post, domain.com/contact etc

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of pages, a [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#mapfunc) might be what you want:

```
RewriteMap oldtonew txt:/path/to/file/map.txt 
RewriteRule ^/index.php?pageid=([0-9]+) ${oldtonew:$1}
```

contents of map.txt:

```
1    /blog-post
2    /contact
3    /foo
4    /bar
```

*Edit*

If you only want to redirect all the old pages to one of the new ones, you don't have to bother with rewritemap:

```
RewriteRule ^/index.php?pageid=([0-9]+) /path/to/new/page
```

Comment: thanks for the info, the site was very deep before so mapping would be too much i think. What we hoped to do was just redirect all previous links to the home page if possible.

Comment: @Brob: Ah, that makes it alot simpler. Updated the answer with another example.